# how to use phpfastcache?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

this is my main query in index.php file

I am trying to cache this query with [phpfastcache](http://www.phpfastcache.com/)

```
$shorting = $conn->prepare("SELECT text,time FROM small WHERE active='0' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10");
$shorting->execute();
while($obj = $shorting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

<div id="lastnews_title">
<div><?php echo $obj->text; ?></div>
<div style="text-align:left">
<?php echo timeTonow($obj->time); ?>
</div>
```

this is an example in phpfastcache site

```
// Require Library
require_once("../phpfastcache/phpfastcache.php");

// simple Caching with:
$cache = phpFastCache();

// Try to get $products from Caching First
// product_page is "identity keyword";
$products = $cache->get("product_page");

if($products == null) {
    $products = "DB QUERIES | FUNCTION_GET_PRODUCTS | ARRAY | STRING | OBJECTS";
    // Write products to Cache in 10 minutes with same keyword
    $cache->set("product_page",$products , 600);
}

// use your products here or return it;
echo $products;
```

I write `require_once("../phpfastcache/phpfastcache.php");` in my index.php

I dont know how to insert my query in this cache class?

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have a set of `<php>` tags surrounding this set of php statements

```
$shorting = $conn->prepare("SELECT text,time FROM small WHERE active='0' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10");
$shorting->execute();
while($obj = $shorting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
```

this code doesn't look like it functions, and I think that is the point you are getting at here.

you should study some of the basics of PHP.  I know very Little about PHP and what you are trying to do, but I know that this is bad "php" grammar.

this is what your first code block should look like:

```
$shorting = $conn->prepare("SELECT text,time FROM small WHERE active='0' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10");
$shorting->execute();
while($obj = $shorting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo "<div id='lastnews_title'>";
    echo "<div> $obj->text </div>";
    echo "<div style='text-align:left'>";
    echo timeTonow($obj->time); 
    echo "</div>"
}
```

you are missing an ending `div` tag

I left out the php tags because I assume that this is a php document and that all of this is enclosed in a set of php tags already  `<php> </php>`