# Ajax cache not working for some reason

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, caching

I am having problems understanding why and how my ajax requests are not being cached.

I've read up on about 50-60 different articles on the web that say this should work.

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "GET",
  cache: true,
  url: 'get.php',
});
```

but when I look in firebug or developer net tab. I keep seeing the page being loaded with a 200 response code which means it is loading a fresh new page instead of an older cached.

So to make the test even more basic, I added a blank separate page purely display a datetime, so I can see if it is being cached or not.

It did not work, datetime was still being updated.

So next I tried to set the headers like this on get.php:

```
$cache_length=600;

header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 3600));
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$cache_length");
header("User-Cache-Control: max-age=$cache_length");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

That still doesn't cache it.

Then I tried this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "GET",
  cache: true,
  url: 'get.php',
});
```

Still the same problem, no caching taking place

Then I also tried this, still no caching

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.ajax({ 
      type: "GET",
      cache: true,
      url: 'get.php',
    });

Then I tried this, still no caching

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
$.ajax({ 
  type: "GET",
  cache: true,
  url: 'get.php',
});
```

So I am baffled why it won't cache it, when examples online seem to make it pretty simple to cache it by specifying cache:true.

No matter what i try, I am still seeing an updated time in get.php, make me believe that cache is still not working, but don't understand know why

How do I cache the page for one hour?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding how the cache variable works.  The default value for cache is `true`, so you don't even have to set it.  It doesn't actually tell your browser or computer or server to cache anything.  The main purpose of the variable is to be able to set it to `false` so it forces the browser to *not* cache the page by way of adding `"_={timestamp}"` to the GET parameters.

Further explanation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Keeping the value at true simply means the response will behave like any other page.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, that answers the initial bit about the ajax request, so then how to get a page to be cached? Does the page sending the response need to have some specific headers to tell the browser to cache it? If so how is this done in PHP, as you see above I tried a few things that didn't work

Comment: That's a very open-ended question as there are a lot of different ways to do things. You are sort of on the right track, but just telling the headers to cache the page is only one step of the process.  When it gets to your PHP code it's still going to execute it on-the-fly.  When you cache a page, there still has to be another part to check whether or not to load the cached version, or generate it dynamically.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3787258/1307183 for a basic example.