# How to make php create an html file with rendered php code?

Tags: php, html, converters, render

I've just begun learning php and I have created a php page that creates pages dynamically. For example I have used includes for menu.php, header.php and so on.
I would like php to create a html file that contains the rendered php automatically.

My project:
Every time I refresh the index page completely different content loads and I would like to have It automatically create a html version.

Comment: please, explain a bit more what you want, try to search online, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787125/how-to-cache-dynamic-php-page may be what you want

Comment: You really need to explain this problem better. Please give a valid use scenario and potentially some screen shots if they make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to store the output generated by the PHP script to a file, right? In this case, you could use output buffering:

```
<?php
// Turn on output buffering
ob_start();

// Create the HTML page content
print '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body><button type="button">Button</button></body></html>';

// At the end of the PHP script, write the buffered content to a file
$content = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('/my/html/pages/page.html', $content);

// Output the HTML to the browser
print $content;
?>
```

Visit [php.net](http://php.net) for more info.